# Sending files and data using jQuery Iframe transport plugin

Tags: jquery, iframe, plugins, transport

I want to upload files and a few hidden fields to server using jQuery iframe-transport plugin.

http://cmlenz.github.com/jquery-iframe-transport/

I have form on the page, that contains inputs with type 'file' and 'hidden'. 
I use code:

```
$("#fileupload").submit(function() {
    progress(1);
    var data = $(":hidden", this).serializeArray();
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax(this.action, {
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        files: $(":file", this),
        iframe: true
    }).complete(function(data) {
        progress(0);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Variable 'data' contains:

```
[ { name: "description_0", value: "111"}, { name: "description_1", value: "222"}]
```

Files are sent to server, but data is not. I see information about files in Post tab in Firebug. There is no data info.

Can someone explain, why data info is not sent?

Answer (score 0):

try with [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) form, and the input's with type "file" don't send: "Data from file select elements is not serialized".